# Large custom GCP metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics

What's the best way of creating large custom metrics in GCP?

We are running some compute instances, and want to **track some custom values**, e.g. the quality of an algorithm, and visualize the data into dashboards.
Our current solution is to write log messages, and use **Logs-based metrics**.
That works, but it requires that we write a log message for every single value, which sounds kinda inefficient (lots of meta infos, filtering log messages, ...) and amounts to a quite high logging bill.

Is there a better, more efficient way of managing custom metrics?

I've seen that you can create custom metrics, and add new points to them with the monitorin API (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics), however those are rate limited, and you can write just one point each 10 seconds, which is far too less, and you get errors like the following:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 One or more TimeSeries could not be written: 
One or more points were written more frequently than the maximum sampling period configured for the metric.: timeSeries[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options for custom metrics in GCP you may want to check out:

1. [Custom metrics with OpenCensus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OCaswinaxM)
2. [Custom Metrics with Prometheus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XToKHYXSUyc)
3. [Custom metrics with OpenTelemetry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHJKH2-w8OY)